# Jquery positioning with position()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make something like this:
[image]

So when I click on text "Hi, ..." it `toggle();` dropdown menu and positions that menu like on image.

But when I resize browser I get something like this:

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L22ptmzm/1/)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your code :

```
var x = $(".icons").position();                     
document.getElementById("user_menu").style.left = x.left + "px";
```

Inside `$(".icons").click(function(){`

It will recalculate the position each time you click to open the dropdown.

**Edit :**

You can also bind the position to the window.onresize event :

```
$(".icons").click(function(){
    $("#user_menu").toggle();
    calculatePosition();
});

$(window).resize(calculatePosition);

function calculatePosition() {
    var x = $(".icons").position();                     
    document.getElementById("user_menu").style.left = x.left + "px";
}
```

Thanks to the code above, your element will be repositionned when you resize the window (avoid the offset when the dropdown is opened)

Comment: Thanks for advice, I will use it in my project